# Need help retrieving value from list

Tags: map, list

Approver__c is junction object on property object. while property object is related to Project object with lookup relation.And Project object is connected with Opportunity with look up. I need to get managerNamefrom Approver__c  to Opportunity object.

I have tried getting value using SOQL query with the following code. Below code does not give any error but I don't get value wither. I am calling this class from before Insert trigger. I have tested it using debug statement and calling is fine. But I am not getting value in the Manager_Name__c field on opportunity?

Please help me understanding where i am doing wrong?

```
public static Map<Id,Approver__c> GetManagerName(Opportunity[] opps)
 {
      Id[] Propertyids = new Id[]{};

     for (Opportunity opp : opps)
     {
         if(opp.PropertyID__c!= null)
         {
             Propertyids.add(opp.PropertyID__c);
         }
        System.debug('After property Id' + Propertyids);
     }

     List<Approver__c> ApproverList = new List<Approver__c>();
     Map<Id,Approver__c> Managers = new Map<Id,Approver__c>();


if (!Propertyids.isEmpty())
        {
            ApproverList = [Select a.Role__c, a.Approver_1__c, a.Approver_2__c,Property__r.Id from Approver__c a Where Id in :Propertyids and a.Role__c = 'Manager'];

    }  

    for(Approver__c assmt: ApproverList) 
    {
        Managers.put(assmt.Property__r.Id, assmt);
        Opportunity.Manager_Name__c = Managers.get(assmt.Approver_1__c).Name;
        System.debug('in for loop' + Opportunity.Manager_Name__c);

     } 

     return Managers;
 }
```

Comment: In your if(!Propertyids.isEmpty()) section, you have your select statement using variables that I do not see defined elsewhere.  Also, in your last for loop with Approver__c, you are putting something into MallManagers, but I do not see MallManagers defined anywhere, either.

Comment: Hi @smckitrick  in select statement those fields I am retrieving from the Approver__c object are what i need as Manager name. so approver_1__c is the text field on that object which contains name of approver. I want that on the bases of their role and Id . So I am queriend all of those. 

manager__c is the field on opportunity I only need to put value on that field thats why I am using at last to assidn value from list.

Comment: I have edited that for loop. Please relook at that.

Comment: For the select statement, I was referring to the variable "a" (a.Approver_1__c, etc.).  I don't see the "a" listed as a variable anywhere else in the pasted code.

Comment: that is inside the select statment only if you look at the from part in that 
from Approver__c "a"

Comment: What kind of field is Opportunity.Manager_Name__c and what kind of field is Approver__c.Approver_1__c? Are those text fields or lookup fields?

Comment: Approver__c.Approver_1__c is lookup and Opportunity.Manager_Name__c is text field.

Comment: There is also some strange code in your final loop. Why do you do this?

            Managers.put(assmt.Property__r.Id, assmt);
            Opportunity.Manager_Name__c = Managers.get(assmt.Approver_1__c).Name;

Comment: Opportunity.Manager_Name__c = Managers.get(assmt.Approver_1__c).Name; 
I am using this code to get the value in that field

Comment: Managers.put(assmt.Property__r.Id, assmt); 
this code is not that importnat . it is just there for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues so I took a stab at rewriting your code:

Assuming that you are doing this in a before trigger?
Assuming that there is only ONE Approver record for each property

```
public static Map<Id,Approver__c> GetManagerName(Opportunity[] opps)
 {
      Set<Id> Propertyids = new Set<ID>();

     for (Opportunity opp : opps)
     {
         if(opp.PropertyID__c!= null)
         {
             Propertyids.add(opp.PropertyID__c);
         }
        System.debug('After property Id' + Propertyids);
     }

     Map<ID,Approver__c> propertyToApprovers = New Map<ID,Approver__c>();

     for(Approver__c app : [Select Role__c, Approver_1__r.Name, 
                                    Approver_2__r.Name,Property__c
                                    From Approver__c
                                    Where Property__c in :Propertyids 
                                    AND Role__c = 'Manager')]){

        propertyToApprovers.put(app.Property__c,app);
     }


     for(Opportunity o : opps){
        Approver__c tmp = propertyToApprovers.get(o.PropertyID__c);
        o.Manager_Name__c = tmp == null ? null : tmp.Approver_1__r.Name;
     }

     return propertyToApprovers;

 }
```

Not sure how this is being called so it assumes it is a before trigger thus no DML.

Also, not a lot of explanation as there was just too much that was not making sense..

Comment: This looks like a good solution to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric.

why are you trying to get o.PropertyID__c in the last for loop statement ?
 Approver__c tmp = propertyToApprovers.get(o.PropertyID__c);

I want to put value of approver__1__c in the  o.Manager_Name__c field?

Comment: Because the map key is by Property ID. In the next line if the property was a valid key I put the Approver name in the manager name field

Comment: Excellent @eric that solved my problem .I got the value now. Really appreciate your help. There is small error in query I am correcting that answer now. It was not mistake form your end , I have wrote it incorrectly initially so. 
again thank you so much

Comment: @dphil - Thanks for changing back the incorrect community edit....

Comment: @Ricky - My select statement was correct. you do not need to `__r.id` as the field __c is the ID of the related record

Comment: @eric will it still compare Id from PropertyID__c field as it only contains property salesforce id? as we are comparing with that id and not with property it self.

Comment: Propertyid__c is the same thing as propertyid__r.id

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have an error in your SoQL:

Based on you adding the field "Property__r.Id", I assume that the the ID of Approver__c is not the same of the Id of Property.

In that case, your SoQL's where clause should look like this:

```
 Where Property__r.Id in :Propertyids and a.Role__c = 'Manager'];
```

Comment: Hey that is good catch. I have changed that query with property__r.Id but still not getting value in Opportunity.Manager_Name__c.

Comment: I think it has to do with the way you're constructing your Managers map. First you "put" using "assmt.Property__r.Id" as the key. then you try to retrieve using  the same record's "assmt.Approver_1__c" field.... That will never work. :)